# Renamed user in Active Directory/Exchange not correctly displaying in Outlook calender

Tags: active-directory, exchange, outlook, windows-sbs-2011

We renamed a user via the SBS2011 console.  It appeared to update everywhere.  However when other domain users use Outlook to connect to the user's shared calendar it still has the old username.

Ex: rename User1 to User2.  When User3 connects to User2's shared calendar it still shows User1's name in the calendars list.

Active directory has the correct info, and everything seems to be in place, our only issue is with the wrong name showing up in the shared Outlook calenders. Removing and recreating the account isn't really an option because of all the information tied to this specific user's account.

Why would this be happening?

Comment: Did you try to disable the Cached Exchange Mode and then enable it again?

Comment: Are you sure you changed the name correctly?  I have frequently seen people change the CN (Common Name) of a user object, but not update the displayName attribute, or they do it the other way resulting in a user that is only half-way renamed.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the user name appears correctly in the Global Address List and Offline Address Book, you may need to reset the Outlook Nickname cache, as described here:

**How to reset the nickname and the automatic completion caches in Outlook**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287623

---

Microsoft Outlook maintains a nickname list that is used by both the automatic name checking feature and the automatic completion feature. The nickname list is generated automatically as you use Outlook. If the nickname cache is corrupted, Outlook may be unable to identify recipients, may offer incorrect recipients when automatically completing the email address, or may send the message to the wrong person.

Unlike earlier versions of Outlook that store the nickname cache in a file on your computer, Outlook 2010 stores the nickname cache in your primary message store. For example, if you are using a Microsoft Exchange Server account, your nickname cache is stored in a hidden message in your mailbox.

Outlook 2010

- Open a new email message.
- Type the first few characters of the nickname cache entry that you want to remove from the cache.
- When the entry appears in the list of suggested names, move your mouse pointer over the name until it becomes highlighted, but do not click the name.
- When the “X” icon appears next to the highlighted name, click X to remove the name from the list.

Outlook 2007 or Outlook 2003

- Open a new email message
- Type the first few characters of the nickname cache entry that you want to remove from the cache.
- When the entry appears in the list of suggested names, use the UP and DOWN arrow keys on your keyboard to select the entry, and then press DELETE on your keyboard.

Comment: I'm missing something here...The nickname cache is only accessible to the user who created the entries, so how is it involved in the display name *other* users see?